# Adding GooglePlay to Android Studio causes compile failure

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a hello world type app that compiles fine in Android Studio.  I want to bring in Google Maps to it. As soon as I add support into Android Studio and try to compile it gives me an error.

Here is what I did after creating the sample project and seeing that it built fine.

File-Project Structure->SDKs. Have Classpath highlighted then click the plus. After that a dialog appears and I select this:
C:\AndroidRelated\android_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar

I then go back and select Build->Rebuild Project. At this point all is well. I then add this line:

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

I then rebuild and this time I get this:

Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':ShowGoogleMaps:compileDebug'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

What is going on here?

I've tried closing the project, reopening it, closing Android Studio and starting again, etc.

Really want to like Android Studio too!

Thanks.

Comment: I've not tried this myself to know, but I'm guessing the more detailed output from the failure may give more clues, can you find that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you are doing an import of the project into your IDE, but you are doing builds via Gradle. Let's try using ALL Gradle based dependency management instead.

Try this instead:

1. Open up the SDK manager
2. Under "Extras", select "Android Support Repository" and "Google Repository". Install them. See screenshot. [image]

(You may need to remove the Play Services library from your project.)

In the dependencies section of your build.gradle file, add some variation of these:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
```

You may need to remove:

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

Now do a "gradlew clean" from the command line and try again. You'll find out what's going o with the --debug option if you are still having problems, but it should build. I'm not using the Maps project, but I AM using Play Services for authentication. Here's a [project using the YouTube APIs](https://github.com/ikai/youtube-android-gradle) that DOES work with this flow. I know for a fact that project works, so you can use that as a baseline to see if you've set up your environment correctly.

Note that, depending on your platform, you may need to restart the IDE after adding new dependencies. Android Studio is still in Early Access, so it's raw around the edges. I've heard from folks that the "Sync Gradle Project" button works for them, but I had issues when I tried using it.